# expo router unable to send link as parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-router

I'm writing a react native application that lists movies. Since I'm using a shared element, I need to send the image url as a parameter. I can't add any urli to the parameter. navigation does not redirect and gives the following logs.

```
[CoreServices] Failed to open URL /tabs/detail?id=1&image=https://www.google.com/: Error
Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "invalid input parameters"
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=invalid input parameters, _LSLine=249,
_LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:fileHandle:options:completionHandler:]}

 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Unable to open URL: /tabs/detail?id=1&image=https://www.google.com/
Error: Unable to open URL: /tabs/detail?id=1&image=https://www.google.com/
```

Answer (score -1):

this is how i solved the problem

```
  const itemPress = (item: { id: number; image: string }) => {
    const encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent("https://www.google.com/");

    router.push({
      pathname: `/tabs/detail`,
      params: {
        id: item.id,
        image: encodedUrl,
      },
    });
  };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).